# Drywall requriements for bathrooms

Tags: drywall, shower

Is green board or cement board required on shower/tub walls in massachusetts?

Comment: I think what's going over the wall might be more important than a code requirement.  What's the final plan for the shower/tub?

Comment: Green board is _never_ required (nor is it particularly beneficial).

Comment: Have you asked your AHJ? They know and will tell you.